# How can i use 6 bits to store value?

Tags: c++, types, bit-manipulation, bit, flags

My data unit (a network packet header) i am currently working on has 2 flags in its definition, stored in a byte field and accessed via bitwise operators. Unfortunately, i need only 2 bits and thinking what i can do with other 6 bits? Can i use them to store number?

Can i use them to store some internal *state code* (value range smaller than `char`?) and do not just waste them.

Is there any data types smaller than byte and how can i use them in C++? If no, should i waste those bits and left them without meaning?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to with those bits.

Comment: You could use them to store whatever you wanted. You would simply have to use bit/masking to set extract the value(s). As for C++, it defines "byte" in an implementation-dependent way, which is `sizeof char = 1` but may or may not be 8 bits. So, no, you can't implement smaller-ranged values _natively_, but it's trivial to do if you provide your own handlers.

Comment: You can allocate unused bits any which way you desire, including storing a small number in them. However, access to sub-byte entities is typically via bit operations or bit fields, either of which may be inefficient. Also, there is a long sad history of "unused" (often, "reserved") bits becoming used later on, causing serious problems with software that usurped those bits for its own purposes. So unless you are *really* pressed for space, I would suggest leaving those unused bits alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a bit field, as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Adapted from that page:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
 // 6-bit unsigned field,
 // allowed values are 0...63
 unsigned int b : 6;
};
int main()
{
    S s = {7};
    ++s.b;
    std::cout << s.b << '\n'; // output: 8
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Works as expected, i hope.

Comment: An unsigned value of 6 bits can hold values from 0 to **63**.

Comment: @IInspectable i've tested, the max value is 127. (128 is 0, 129 is 1).

Comment: @Joker: Please show your creative test code. The max value you can store in n digits is base^n-1. In a base-2 system that is 63.

Comment: @IInspectable You're correct. Don't know, i was sleepy. Thanks, 63 is still great allowed range.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there is no datatype smaller than a `char`, which is - by definition - one byte. However, you do not need a dedicated datatype to access the bits of a value. [Bitwise logic and Bitwise Shift operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) are sufficient.

If you cannot live with sacrificing 6 bits (this is assuming 8-bit bytes) you might want to consider the [std::vector<bool>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) specialization. Note, though, that there are a number of restrictions and differences to a regular [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Another option to make individual (consecutive) bits of a datatype accessible by name is to use [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field):

```
struct S {
    unsigned int flags : 2;
    unsigned int state : 6;
};
static_assert( sizeof( S ) == 1, "Packing is implementation-defined." );
```

This declares a structure that can hold two pieces of information: `flags` and `state`, which occupy 2 and 6 bits, respectively. Adjacent bit fields are usually packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined).

Comment: It is not great to duplicate other's answers in the **same** question.

Comment: @Joker: Adding information is hardly *duplication*. Noting that the behavior for bit fields is implementation-defined may be useful. If you understand the implications.